# Wordpress query custom meta key

Tags: wordpress, meta-key, post-meta

I've added a postmeta (popular_posts) see image below. But when I query posts with meta key "popular_posts" like in below I've had no result:

```
new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key'=>'popular_posts' ))
```

Some one can explain me how to properly retrieve that have meta key "popular_posts" ?

[image]

Comment: Are you you created new custom post type? or you are using default post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simple way to get post by their meta.

```
$myquery = new WP_Query( "post_type=post&meta_key=popular_posts");
```

Or You can use this :

```
$second_loop = get_posts( array(
  'meta_key'   => 'popular_posts',
  'meta_value !=' => '',
```

) );

Comment: `new WP_Query( "post_type=post&meta_key=popular_posts");`
has helped me.

Thanks @Lathiya Fenil

Answer (score 1):

```
    $popular_posts_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'meta_query' => array(
           'meta_value' => array(
                'key' => 'popular_posts',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC' 
    )));

    $popular_posts = new WP_Query($popular_posts_args);
```

As your meta key store numeric value. It is better to define the type in the argument. Then you can loop through `$popular_posts`